# Restrict a CSS file affecting inside a DIV or container

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, styles

I am working in a large application. Development started long back. There are around 500+ HTML pages in the application. Now planning to redesign each page. Please find the below CSS hirearchy.

```
|
|- bootstrap3.css
|- framework.css 
|- theme.css
|- select2.css
|- bootstrap5.css ( New for revamped parts only)
|- rev_style.css ( New for revamped parts only)
```

Would likes to remove the old css files once the revamp completes.

New revamp part is under a  new class something like `<div class="rev_02"></div>` . New SASS files are creating with this superclass hirearchy.

Now the problem is old css files are affecting the styles and alignments of newly revamped components. For avoiding that need a bunch of more code with `!important` tag and css lines.

My question is - Any method restrict old css files inside a DIV or a container in a HTML page ?

Comment: create css [@layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to override old styles, such as using CSS modules or Sass to nest classes in the upgraded design. The goal is to increase the CSS specificity of the class or id being used on the div or container, or to restrict the whole style if resources permit. I have provided links to articles on CSS specificity, CSS modules, and Sass nesting that can help you understand these concepts. I hope these resources will help you to solve the problem.

- [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)
- [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
- [SASS Nesting](https://medium.com/@max.codes/scss-sass-nesting-intelligently-the-optimal-way-6b92ed3d7f79)
- [SASS Nesting](https://www.koderhq.com/tutorial/sass/nesting/)